# Content Version SOQL - WIth custom field in the Where clause Return as null

Tags: apex, soql, contentversion

I have a custom field on Content Version - but When I try to have a  SOQL and receive the data its return as null.

The next line is working :

```
ContentVersion testContentInsert = new ContentVersion();
testContentInsert.Title = fileName;
testContentInsert.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64decode(b64File);
testContentInsert.PathOnClient =fileName;
testContentInsert.Unique_Key__c = itemKey + dateKey;

insert testContentInsert;
 
List<ContentVersion> cvList = [select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion WHERE Id =:testContentInsert.Id];//Recived the data!
```

But this line is not working:

```
 ContentVersion testContentInsert = new ContentVersion();
    testContentInsert.Title = fileName;
    testContentInsert.VersionData = EncodingUtil.base64decode(b64File);
    testContentInsert.PathOnClient =fileName;
    testContentInsert.Unique_Key__c = itemKey + DateKey;



    insert testContentInsert;
 
    List<ContentVersion> cvList = [select id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion WHERE Unique_Key__c =:testContentInsert.Unique_Key__c ]; // NULL
```

If I run the same Line from Developer Console and not in same class its working. but in the same class its give me empty results

Any Help with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is mentioned in the docs for [ContentVersion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm)

> Note: Depending on how files are shared, queries on ContentDocument
> and ContentVersion without specifying an ID won't return all files a
> user has access to. For example, if a user only has access to a file
> because they have access to a record that the file is shared with, the
> file won't be returned in a query such as "SELECT Id FROM
> ContentDocument."

Under the Usage section, this is also mentioned (emphasis mine)

> To query a file that is shared only with a record, **you must specify
> the content ID of the file.**

Looks like a test class and I'm not seeing the code setting `ContentDocumentId` on the ContentVersion?

I'd go about trying to build out the test data to reflect the scenario in your org. A ContentVersion of a `ContentDocument` that has a [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) setting the appropriate `ShareType` and `Visibility` while relating it to something (record,user) in `LinkedEntityId`.

Comment: My scenario is that I have a force.com site - A user (guest user) can upload files via remote action.
I want to insert those files and later do a connection with a unique key that I gave to the file and I'm about to give to my object.

I dont have the option to pass the Id because remote action is a static function, which my other functions are not - and its VF page's dependent.

That why I want to insert the content version and only after to insert the document link in a different function.

Any recommendation?

Comment: It might be worth putting an [edit] to your question to get at the issue. Maybe even include a little about what the VF page is doing?

Comment: Thanks, it helped me understand my Issue eventually.

Site guest user is really see the records when I put the Ids, So I used DB (custom object that save the Id of the File with a key of the current guest) to make the query work.
Thanks for your help